# How to divide the current price to the last price in the same column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I divide ((89-95)/95)*100 or ((95-100)/100)*100

```
 CREATE TABLE `priceindex` (
          `priceIndexId` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
          `Price` decimal(31,9) DEFAULT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


priceIndexId |    Date    | Price | Currentvalue/previous value
      1      | 2017-11-30 |  100  | 
      2      | 2017-12-06 |  95   | answer should be(95-100)/100)*100 = -0.50
      3      | 2017-12-13 |  89   | answer should be(89-95)/95)*100 = -0.63
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the previous value.  One method uses a correlated subquery.  I would suggest using a subquery for the calculation:

```
select pi.priceIndexId, pi.Date, pi.Price,
       (pi.Price - pi.prev_price) / pi.prev_price as change
from (select pi.*,
             (select pi2.price
              from priceindex pi2
              where pi2.date < pi.date
              order by pi2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_price
      from priceindex pi
     ) pi;
```